# id attribute in eloquent collection changes when converting to an array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with uuid's as the id column. I do a query using eloquent and it returns the correct information. I have attached an image below because its a big object to write.

[image]

So theres 2 items in this collection, they follow the same format but as you can see the first item has the id field which is the correct uuid.

To print this i am doing

```
$offers = Offer::list($display, false);
dd($offers);
```

So offers is the collection.

If i do...

```
$offers = Offer::list($display, false);
dd($offers->toArray());
```

I get the following...

[image]

The id has magically changed into single integers instead of the uuid string I had before.

Does anyone know why it would be doing this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `$incrementing` property on your model to false, [it is documented here on the primary keys section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions). By default Laravel assumes that the `id` field on your model is an incrementing integer, that is why models automatically cast `id` fields to integers.

Comment: @WillDaniels mark the answer as `the answer` for your question to reward the help